# How do I add an admin notice within javascript in the admin interface for posts?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, notices

I want to use javascript to add a notice to the top of the wordpress page just like they do when auto-saving the page. But in looking at the DOM, I don't see any special div that I could find to add my notice to:

**THIS IS THE DIV WHERE WORDPRESS's NOTICES ARE**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Edit Page <a href="http://my-site.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page" class="add-new-h2">Add New</a></h2>
    <div style="display: block;" id="local-storage-notice" class="hidden updated">
        <p class="local-restore">
            The backup of this post in your browser is different from the version below. <a class="restore-backup" href="#">Restore the backup.</a>
        </p>
        <p class="undo-restore hidden">
            Post restored successfully.     <a class="undo-restore-backup" href="#">Undo.</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Is there a javascript function wordpress has that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `F:\sites\wp-git\wp-admin\js\common.js`:

```
$('div.updated, div.error').not('.below-h2, .inline').insertAfter( $('div.wrap h2:first') );
```

If your notice has the class `updated` or `error`, it will be set after the first `h2` automatically. When you create custom messages, make sure you are using one of these classes. Then you can just append them to `body`, and WordPress will move them to the proper place.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if those classes and divs have been there since 3.0? I don't want to rely on anything that's not documented and could change.

Comment: @DonRhummy They are very old, and they will probably not change, because that would break too many plugins.